# Using double quotes in Perl script

Tags: perl, escaping, double-quotes

Can anyone help in resolving this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $teststr="\"abcd\"";

print "\nTestStr: $teststr\n";

`echo "$teststr" >> \/home\/folder\/samplequotes.txt`;
```

Output of the program above:

```
$ perl quotes1.pl

TestStr: "abcd"

$ cat samplequotes.txt

abcd
```

The problem i'm facing is that the double quotes in string are not getting into the text file.

Ideally, the contents of the samplequotes.txt file should have been:

```
"abcd"
```

Can anybody please tell me what would be the issue here ??

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is mixing Perl and shell; that's two similar but not identical sets of quoting conventions, and understanding the interaction between them is hard (since you need to understand both separately, as well as how they interact).

Perl expands:

```
`echo "$teststr" >> \/home\/folder\/samplequotes.txt`;
```

into:

```
echo ""abcd"" >> /home/folder/samplequotes.txt
```

and the shell treats the adjacent double quotes as empty, hence you get `abcd` in the file.  If you don't want the shell interpreting the double quotes, write:

```
`echo '$teststr' >> /home/folder/samplequotes.txt`;
```

which the shell gets to see as:

```
echo '"abcd"'  >> /home/folder/samplequotes.txt
```

However, it is better not to run a shell simply to do the echo like that; it would be far more sensible to have Perl open the file and add the output to it and then close the file.

```
{
open my $fh, '>>', "/home/folder/samplequotes.txt" or die;
print $fh $teststr;
}
```

The braces limit the scope of the file handle to the four lines of code shown, and automatically close the file when the file handle goes out of scope.

The backslashes in the file name in your code are all rather pointless too.  Perl removes them (AFAICT) so the shell doesn't get to see them.

Answer (score 2):

Use perl's file processing to write to the file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $teststr = '"abcd"';
my $file = '/home/folder/samplequotes.txt';

print "\nTestStr: $teststr\n";

open my $fh, '>>', $file;
print $fh $teststr;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But my actual problem was passing a string as an argument from one function to another which contains double quotes.

Ex. $string1="<a href=\"https://abcd.com\"> 

When I try passing $string1 as argument, the double quotes are gettig ignored. If you help me how to crack this, would be really great.

Comment: Your problem is unclear.  If the above question does not completely and accurately describe your setup, then **edit your post**.  Do not post a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25081901/1733163), as that will get you less attention.  Instead, read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and attempt to clarify your goal in the above question.

Answer (score 2):

If you modify your input string to include the backslashes for your shell to interpret like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $teststr="\\\"abcd\\\"";

print "\nTestStr: $teststr\n";
`echo "$teststr" >> \/home\/folder\/samplequotes.txt`;
```

Then you will get the desired output to your samplequotes.txt file. The problem here was that your shell wasn't interpreting your input the way you thought it was.

Hope that helps!